# Prolog, Definite Clause Grammar

Tags: prolog, dcg

Some code I wrote for a definite clause grammar
I followed the book "Learn Prolog Now" very closely

```
lex(the,det(single)).
lex(the,det(plural)).
lex(a,det(single)).
lex(some,det(plural)).
lex(at,det(single)).

lex(student,n(single)).
lex(students,n(plural)).
lex(assignment,n(single)).
lex(assignments,n(plural)).
lex(teacher,n(single)).
lex(teachers,n(plural)).
lex(lecture,n(single)).
lex(lecture,n(plural)).
lex(school,n(single)).
lex(home,n(single)).

lex(does,v(single)).
lex(do,v(plural)).
lex(corrects,v(single)).
lex(correct,v(plural)).
lex(writes,v(single)).
lex(write,v(plural)).
lex(gives,v(single)).
lex(give,v(plural)).

lex(his,pro(single)).
lex(her,pro(single)).
lex(their,pro(plural)).

lex(and,conj).
lex(while,conj).

s--> s, conj, s.
s--> np(X),vp(X).
np(X)--> det(X),n(X);pro(X), n(X).
vp(X)--> v(X), np(X).
vp(X)--> v(X).
det(X)--> [A],{lex(A,det(X))}.
pro(X)--> [A],{lex(A,pro(X))}.
v(X)--> [A],{lex(A,v(X))}.
n(X)--> [A],{lex(A,n(X))}.
```

Below is a query I asked for the above code

3 ?- s([the,student,does,his,assignment],[]).
ERROR: Out of local stack

I already tried repositioning the lexicon but that didn't work
As for syntax errors, nothing was picked up when I compiled it

Sorry if I didn't write the question well but I don't know what else to say, if you need any more information about the code leave a comment and I'll try answer as best I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that s//0 is left recursive. You should amend the first rule.
For instance

```
s --> p, conj, s.
p --> np(X),vp(X).
...
```